# Converter Int para String em C++

Tags: c++

Como eu faço para a *String* `resultado` receber o valor *int* de `cont3` e o valor *char* de `c[cont]`?

```
resultado=" ";
resultado=resultado+to_string(**cont3**)+to_string(**c[cont1**]);
```

Tentei usar o `to_string()` mas não resolveu meu problema.

Comment: Dê uma olhada nessa pergunta no SO em inglês, tem vários exemplos, simples de entender: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191757/how-to-concatenate-a-stdstring-and-an-int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer desta forma:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string resultado = " ";
  int n = 1;
  char l = 'a';

  resultado = resultado + std::to_string(n) + l;

  std::cout << resultado;
}
```

Resultado já é uma string, n é do tipo int então é convertido com `std::to_string` e l é char e pode ser concatenado diretamento.

```
resultado = resultado + std::to_string(n) + l;
```

[Resultado](http://cpp.sh/53yfq)

> Este código é para C++11

Comment: Deve deixar o aviso que tem de ser c++11

Comment: @Isac, coloquei, obrigado

Comment: Fiz isso, mas ficou com o seguinte erro:
'to_string' was not declared in this scope

Comment: Você incluiu a lib string? E a sua versão é a 11?

Comment: Consegui aqui, muito obrigado!!